# How do I get my bounty points?

Tags: support

My answer to a +50 bounty [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/218409/error-starting-postgresql-server-on-ubuntu) has been accepted. How do I get the bounty? My understanding is that the OP has to specifically allocate the bounty. What if he decided not to or forgets to?

Comment: If he were to decide not to, or forgot to, that's up to him/her. Nobody is under any obligation to actually award bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Patience - looks to me like you have it now.

Comment: Yes, thanks :) I was concerned that it was possible for the OP to forget to allocate them.

Comment: While you were awarded bounty in this instance please remember that the OP can accept the answer and still award bounty to someone else. The two are quite separate.

Comment: Seems like an odd system, "I like your answer, but this other guy gets the bounty."